# Difference between results from Python and C

Tags: python, c

I wrote very simple program in C (PI computation) and I got result like this:
3.1406174152499528235728265546100601568468846380710601806640625

Result doesn't look like proper PI then I found code in Python on internet I ran it  and got something like that:
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749 - Proper PI.

Then I implemented Python algorithm in C with exactly the same way and I got result like that:
3.1406174152499528235728265546100601568468846380710601806640625

Why results form Python and C from the same algorithm are so different and how to fix C code to get right result ??

Python code:

```
from decimal import*

precision = 100

getcontext().prec = 100

a = 1
b = Decimal(1) / Decimal(2).sqrt()
t = Decimal(1) / Decimal(4)
p = 1
pi = 0
for x in range(0, precision):
    nextA = (a + b) / 2
    nextB = (a * b).sqrt()
    nextT = t - p * ((a - nextA) ** 2)
    nextP = 2 * p
    pi = ((a + b) ** 2) / (4 * t)
    a,b,t,p = nextA,nextB,nextT,nextP
print pi
```

C code:

```
long double a = 1;
long double b = 1/sqrt(2);
long double t = 0.25;
long double p = 1;
long double an, bn, tn, pn, myPI;
long int x;
for(x = 0; x < 100; x++)
{
    an = (a + b) / 2;
    bn = sqrt(a * b);
    tn = t - p * ((a - an) * (a - an));
    pn = 2 * p;
    myPI = ((a + b) * (a + b)) / (4 * t);
    a = an; b = bn; t = tn; p = tn;
 }

printf("%.61Lf\n", myPI);
return 0;
```

Comment: You do not have 100 precision in C (without an external library like GMP). `long double` is about 80 *binary* digits precision.

Comment: Actually, neither of these are 'proper' PI; PI is not a rational number, and thus cannot be expressed as a finite fraction, no matter the base.

Comment: Here `proper` means proper up to the number of decimal positions provided.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is a typo in your code, `p = tn;` should be `p = pn;`.

Note: for long doubles use `sqrtl`.

Update: if you print out the approximation for pi after each iteration it doesn't get any better after the *fifth* iteration and only the first 20 digits are correct. for more precision you need better (not builtin) data types.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that bug.

Answer (score 6):

You are asking for more precision than your C floating point variables can provide.  You need to use arbitrary precision arithmetic rather than fixed precision floating point.  Or at the very least use fixed precision arithmetic with a precision value greater than your desired calculation precision.  The Python code sets the precision to 100 to achieve this.

---

Well, @yi_H also found a bug in your code but even when you fix that you won't get the same precision from your C code as from your Python code for the reasons above.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that floating-point numbers (typically 80 bits total) are the most precise numeric data type C has to offer out-of-the-box, and for most real-world computations, that's more than enough (OTOH, a float, no matter how large, cannot exactly represent 0.85 for example, but that aside).

Python has a built-in big-integer type which allows it to represent arbitrarily large integers (and, piggy-backing on this implementation, arbitrarily precise rational numbers). By using these, approximations of PI can be calculated that are far more precise than anything a float can hold.

If you want even more precision, you'll need to find an algorithm that calculates digits one by one, and have it spit them out while calculating.